# calling a function on clicking the dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

Hi I am new to angular js

My requirement is this:

I have an `ul` with some `li`. On clicking the `li` element I have to populate another `ul` as the child of the parent `li`. I am successful in adding the `ul` to `li` but when I click the new `ul->li` the function of the parent `ul` is called. I tried to add $event.preventDefault() but still not working. Am I going in right direction?

### html:

```
<ul class="navigation" ng-repeat='category in fullTree.category[0]' ng-click='dropmenu(category.category_id,category.level,category.has_child_category,$event)'>
    <li>
        <p>{{category.category_name}} <i class="ion-chevron-down" ></i></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

controller:

```
$scope.dropmenu = function (category_id, level, has_child_category, $event) { 
    $.each(somearray[level], function (index, item) {
        $($event.target).append("<ul class='navigation'><li ng-click='dropmenu("+item.category_id+","+item.level+","+item.has_child_category+",$event);$event.preventDefault()'><p>"+item.category_name+"<i class='ion-chevron-down' ></i></p>"+item.name+"</li></ul>")
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopImmediatePropagation

It prevent events from bubbling up.

Coding example i found: (not mine)

http://jsfiddle.net/4hBqJ/20/